# Attribute inspector not editable - FLEX or Javascript

Tags: editing, flex

I am using ArcGIS 10.2. I have an application that is using the editor and the attribute inspector. I need to add a string showing the current date to a field. Everything works but after creating the feature and selecting it again I can see the string in that field in the attribute inspector but the attribute inspector is not editable any more for that feature.

Is it possible to add a string to a field and still have that feature editable in the attribute inspector?

```
var currDateTime:String = ""    
private function drawEnd(event:DrawEvent):void    
   {    
    dateFormatter.formatString = 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:NN:SS';     
 currDateTime = String(dateFormatter.format(dtCurrent) + '.' + dtCurrent.getMilliseconds());       

   FeatureLayerstewardship.addEventListener(FeatureLayerEvent.EDI}TS_STARTING, editsStartingHandler);      
         }  

     private function editsStartingHandler(event:FeatureLayerEvent):void    
            {    
                if (event.adds)    
                {  
                    event.adds[0].attributes['DrawDate']  =  currDateTime;    
                }    
            }
```

Comment: Would you be able to edit your question to include the GIS software and version that you are using, please?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue! Just create a editscomplete event and refresh the feature layer and the attribute inspector!

protected function myFeatureLayerstewardship_editsCompleteHandler(event:FeatureLayerEvent):void

```
{

            myFeatureLayerstewardship.removeEventListener(FeatureLayerEvent.EDITS_STARTING, editsStartingHandler); 

          myFeatureLayerstewardship.refresh();
          myEditor.attributeInspector.refresh();
```

}